# How is the Wii Wheel detected?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, mario-kart-8, mario-kart-wii, wiimote

In both Mario Kart games for the Wii and Wii U, the game shows an icon on players who it tells are playing with a Wii Wheel. I've always wondered -- what mechanism does the console use to detect whether a Wii Wheel is being used? It seems to just be a piece of plastic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wheel icon is shown when the player is using tilt steering with the Wiimote-only controls. It does not matter whether the wheel accessory is involved, which cannot be detected anyway, as it is just a plastic shell around the controller.

Comment: Oh so this is wrong? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/170393/218092

Comment: I'm not sure, it's been a long time and I can't remember if the condition is "tilt controls" or "tilt controls with Wiimote only". In any case, the wheel accessory has nothing to do with it.